# Align text on vertical center of text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

How can I add padding to the icon (or negative padding to the text), to center the text vertical to the icon in the button, when the font-sizes are different?

CSS:

```
.btn {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn .fa {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i> Text</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jBF45/

Comment: Experiment with `line-height`.

Comment: On which class? I tried adding it to btn and fa, but I did not get any useful effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the [CSS line-height property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp). I have created a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/DCX4G/ .

As long as you set the line height equal to the font size for the CSS class btn fa, then it should vertically center correctly.

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
.btn {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn .fa {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.fa-centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 40px;    /* This needs to be the same as .btn .fa font-size */
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>
    <div class="fa-centered">Text</div>
</a> Font Size: 20px ( .btn font-size )
<hr />
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>
    <div class="fa-centered" style="font-size: 30px;">Text</div>
</a> Font Size: 30px
<hr />
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>
    <div class="fa-centered" style="font-size: 25px;">Text</div>
</a> Font Size: 25px
<hr />
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>
    <div class="fa-centered" style="font-size: 10px;">Text</div>
</a> Font Size: 10px
<hr />
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>
    <div class="fa-centered" style="font-size: 5px;">Text</div>
</a> Font Size: 5px
```